# I think I have seen the Almighty Lord in my dream in the form of someone I know or so I thought

Tags: belief, dream

I think I have seen the Almighty Lord in my dream in the form of someone I know or so I thought. I know it's not possible to see The Lord in any form. What happened with me?

Comment: What makes you think what you saw was God? Please elaborate.

Comment: Maybe you just had a dream. You know just random thoughts in your mind mixing and matching. All dreams don't have to have meaning.

Comment: I knew in my dream what I was watching. Or so I thought. I know that it's not possible but in my dream I thought or I knew that I saw The Lord. And in the form of someone I know. Was it Shaytan? Or I imagined the form? May be I imagined the form but heard for sure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because dream interpretation is off-topic [should dream interpretation be on-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/780/should-dream-interpretation-questions-be-on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

According to scholarly opinion (like Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah), it is possible to see Allah in a dream. But it is also possible that devil comes in dream and tells - 'I am Allah'.

The point to note is that in whatever form a believer sees Allah in dream, He is not at all like that, because

> 'There is nothing like unto Him'. (Quran 42:11)

**Important Note**

Another important thing to know is that if, whoever he saw to be the Lord in his dream, commands him to do something against sharia, then very very likely he is devil in his dream. No dream can override what is established by Quran/Sunnah/Ijma'. Because Allah has said,

> 'This day I have perfected for you your religion and completed My favor upon you and have approved for you Islam as religion'(Quran 5:3)

Thus if the person in dream says, don't pray or it is ok to drink alcohol etc., then he (the dreamer) should never follow that. Our deen is established and can't be altered by any dream.

No body can see Allah in this life.
The Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) saw Allah in his dream.

If the dreamer is a righteous person (Islamic righteousness) and the dream does not contain anything haram or commanding anything haram, then maybe that a good news for him. It does not change anything as far as his righteousness goes, it does not mean he is a person of jannah etc. But a believer must always be vigilant that shaitan is not deceiving him, and he must strive to continue to do good deeds util he dies.

For more:
https://islamqa.info/en/14096

Allah knows best!

Comment: "It is possible to see Allah in a dream" I'd like to see sources for that.

Comment: "Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah and others said that it is possible for a person to see his Lord in a dream." - https://islamqa.info/en/14096

Comment: You should add the source to your answer, so I can remove the downvote

Comment: Even I have seen Allah in dream in a form of a person who was giving rewards and punishments in the field of Hasher. But then I woke and realised it was because of oxygen deprivation to my brain, coz I am asthmatic. Our brain can play the weirdest of hallucinations when the oxygen supply is reduced. That's what I have read.

Comment: @The Z. I have added islamqa.info as the reference to my answer. Is it not enough? Please let me know what is the best way.

Comment: Changed my vote.

Comment: Just to add my dream - I saw Allah (or as I felt) in my dream. It was many years ago when I entered into Islam and  had my heart attached to Islam. In my dream, from a distance I saw Allah in Judgement day taking account of a person. It was only a feeling in my heart that He was Allah in the Judgement day. Did I see Allah in my dream or it was someone else? - that Allah know!